# tabbed UI windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to create a tabbed UI in windows phone app's single page.

Closest example would be tabbed UI of MS Office.

When I tap on a tab(which can be a button as well), the available buttons in a `stackpanel` below should change.

What is the best way to achieve this?
I have quite a lot of buttons in 1 panel and there are numerous tabe(3-4). So, manual assignment is not an option.

Comment: You should look into using a Pivot control : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941123(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Well, you *should* use it, actually. Tab controls per se are quite out of place on WP7. As a normal user I'd hate it if an application would force tabs on me that I'd have to tap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Phone equivalent of a tabbed UI control is the [Pivot control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941123%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

In the example below (taken from [PicFx – Windows Phone Picture Effects Application – Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/PicFx--Windows-Phone-Picture-Effects-Application--Part-1)) there are two "tabs" (or pivot items): **Picture** and **Effects**.

[image: Pivot control]

Comment: thanks. i'll see if it best suites my needs.
i'll keep the question open meanwhile.